# Storing INT after CHAR in C requires 7 bytes instead of 4

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, gdb, disassembly

I was looking into the following C snippet:

```
char x = 'a';
int y = 5;
```

After running gdb I encounter the following assembly:

```
mov BYTE PTR [ebp-1], 0x61
mov DWORD PTR [ebp-8], 0x5
```

Why is `ebp` decreased by 7 instead of 4? If I replace `char x = 'a'` with `int x = 2`, I don't see this behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your C implementation, `int` objects must be stored at addresses that are multiples of four, usually due to hardware alignment requirements or features. The address in the EBP register is known to be a multiple of four (and likely a multiple of 16, depending on your C implementation). So `[ebp-5]` would not be at a multiple four bytes, nor would `[ebp-6]` or `[ebp-7]`. The compiler has to go to `[ebp-8]` to get to the next multiple of four.

(`[ebp-2]`, `[ebp-3]`, and `[ebp-4]` are not considered because starting a four-byte `int` at any of those addresses would overlap the byte in `[ebp-1]` used for the `char`.)

Comment: why not `[ebp-4]` isn't that a multiple of 4 (or am I missing something)?

Comment: @thakee nathees: `dword [ebp-4]` overlaps the `byte [ebp-1]` used for the `char`.